# Batch File to organise pictures from mobile phone into folders (on Windows)

Tags: batch-file, create-directory, movefile

I just created my first Batch file, to organise my mobile phone pictures into folders (on Windows).
It worked, I am just wondering if there is a more efficient way in coding this, as in its current form I would have to go through all possible combinations of years and months.

```
if exist 2018*.* md 2018
if exist 2019*.* md 2019
if exist 2020*.* md 2020
move    2018*.* 2018
move    2019*.* 2019
move    2020*.* 2020
if exist 2018\????_03_*.* md 2018\March
if exist 2018\????_04_*.* md 2018\April
if exist 2018\????_05_*.* md 2018\May
move    2018\????_04_*.*    2018\April
move    2018\????_05_*.*    2018\May
move    2018\????_03_*.*    2018\March
if exist 2019\????_03_*.* md 2019\March
if exist 2019\????_04_*.* md 2019\April
if exist 2019\????_05_*.* md 2019\May
move    2019\????_04_*.*    2019\April
move    2019\????_05_*.*    2019\May
move    2019\????_03_*.*    2019\March
if exist 2020\????_03_*.* md 2020\March
if exist 2020\????_04_*.* md 2020\April
if exist 2020\????_05_*.* md 2020\May
move    2020\????_04_*.*    2020\April
move    2020\????_05_*.*    2020\May
move    2020\????_03_*.*    2020\March
```

Comment: A more efficient way? Try PowerShell…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off

for /f "tokens=1,2,* delims=_" %%A in ('
    dir /b /a-d ????_??_*.* ^| findstr /b "20[0-9][0-9]_"
') do (
    for %%D in (
        "01 January"
        "02 February"
        "03 March"
        "04 April"
        "05 May"
        "06 June"
        "07 July"
        "08 August"
        "09 September"
        "10 October"
        "11 November"
        "12 December"
    ) do (
        for /f "tokens=1,2" %%E in ("%%~D") do (
            if "%%~B" == "%%~E" (
                if not exist "%%~A\%%~F\" md "%%~A\%%~F\"
                if exist "%%~A\%%~F\" move "%%~A_%%~B_%%~C" "%%~A\%%~F\" >nul
            )
        )
    )
)
```

This uses the `????_??_*.*` pattern and is allowed if `findstr` detects the 1st four characters as digits of a year in the 21st century with a following underscore. It then gets the month from the 2 digits in the 2nd token. It checks if directory `year\month\` exists and creates it if not exist. If directory `year\month\` exist, copies the file into the directory.

`for` variables:

- `A` year digits
- `B` month digits
- `C` remainder of filename
- `D` month digits and name
- `E` month digits
- `F` month name

View `for /?` for help with understanding a `for` loop.

Comment: Hi Michael, thank you for your reply! That solves my problem and works like charm, I read up on the for loop but it's still a bit tricky for me to read and digest what is actually happening.Where did you define the variables?

Comment: Defined in e.g `for %%D in (`. `%%D` is assigned value `"01 January"`, then assigned value `"02 February"`... Read some sites linked on the [batch-file info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/batch-file/info).